# Upgrade H2 version 2.0.202 from 1.4.200

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-jdbc

1. Hi, we are trying to upgrade 2.0.202 from 1.4.200. We are getting an
   error related to running our tests. While persisting
   data we are getting below error. Any suggestions?

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
NULL not allowed for column "***"; SQL statement:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use H2 2.0.202 with Hibernate ORM 5.6, because `H2Dialect` in Hibernate ORM produces invalid SQL for H2, H2 2.x is more restrictive and doesn't accept it by default.

H2 2.0.204 and later versions (current version is 2.1.210) have a `LEGACY` compatibility mode, it can be enabled by appending `;MODE=LEGACY` to JDBC URL. This mode provides some limited compatibility with old versions of H2.

This trick shouldn't be required for Hibernate ORM 6.0 when it will be released.

***Edited***

Changes for H2 2.x.y were backported to Hibernate ORM 5.6.5.